# How to publish to pubsub with Service Account Key JSON vs Service Account JSON

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

Is this possible?

When I attempt to use the following Service Account Key JSON:

```
{
 "keyAlgorithm": "KEY_ALG_RSA_2048",
 "keyOrigin": "GOOGLE_PROVIDED",
 "name": "projects/XXXX",
 "privateKeyData": "XXXXXX",
 "privateKeyType": "TYPE_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE",
 "validAfterTime": "2019-08-16T19:45:25Z",
 "validBeforeTime": "2029-08-13T19:45:25Z"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
client: pubsub: google: error getting credentials using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable: missing 'type' field in credentials
```

Am I missing something? It apparently only wants to work with Service Account JSON. I'd rather not hand out those credentials.

Any advice?

Comment: Yes, it's expecting service account json with `"type": "service_account"`.  What do you mean by "hand out those credentials"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you are using the raw output from the API `service.projects.serviceAccounts.keys.create`.

Look at the output in your question. The key `privateKeyData` contains the base64 encoded value of the service account JSON key file. Base64 decode that value and use as JSON for input when creating credentials.

Python Example:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
info = json.loads(base64.b64decode(privateKeyData))
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(info)
```

Go Example:

```
import b64 "encoding/base64"
import "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
scope := "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
s, _ := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(privateKeyData)
ctx := context.Background()
creds, err := google.CredentialsFromJSON(ctx, s, scope)
```